# Aframe Camera Switch only works in non VR mode

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, webvr

Sitting on a Study Project right now, building some Scenes in with Aframe. I try to switch between different Cameras in my Aframe Scene, if the User enters a Door to get to the next Scene. I have two of the following Camera Rigs, one for each Scene:

```
<a-entity id="cameraRig" position="10 4 20">
<a-entity id="head" position="0 2 0" camera="" look-controls="pointerLockEnabled:true">
<a-cursor far="30"></a-cursor>
    <a-entity position="0.1 -0.4 0"
      raycaster="objects: .selectable; far: 2"
      teleport-extras
      teleport-controls=
        "cameraRig: #cameraRig;
        teleportOrigin: #head;
        startEvents:starttouch;
        endEvents:endtouch;
        curveShootingSpeed:30;
        hitCylinderRadius:0.3;
        collisionEntities: #tele">
    </a-entity>
 </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

This is my Script for changing the Camera:

```
function Hell() {
 document.getElementById('scene1').setAttribute('visible', 'false');
 document.getElementById('hell').setAttribute('visible', 'true');

 var standartCam = document.querySelector('#head');
 standartCam.setAttribute('camera', 'active', false);

 var hellCamera = document.querySelector('#head2');
 hellCamera.setAttribute('camera', 'active', true);
 }
```

The Switch works until I enter VR-Mode, then the Camera is not switching at all.

I tried to just set a new position for the first CameraRig, but that leads to bugs with the teleport component, where the Camera jumps under the objects it should teleport onto.

How can I get this to work? Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of try and error, I found the solution. 
I was using aframe.io/releases/0.8.0. 
I switched to 0.7.0 and it worked. 
It also works on 0.8.2.